# Updating an array which already exists and pushing new data into the same array

Tags: typescript

I wanted to push a arrays values into another array but also while pushing the data if already exiting data is available it should just update the existing data.
The code is in typescript.

---

```
class itemList{
    constructor(public name: string, public amount: number){}
}

function DisArr(Ar1: itemList[]){
    for(let item of Ar1){
        console.log(item.name + " -- " + item.amount);
    }
}

var Ar1 = [new itemList('Apple',3),
new itemList('Tomato',4),
new itemList('Jam',1)];

var Ar2 = [new itemList('Orange',3),
new itemList('Tomato',8),
new itemList('Grape',20)];

console.log("Array before updating : ");
DisArr(Ar1);
Ar1.push(...Ar2);
console.log("Array before updating : ");
DisArr(Ar1);
```

---

As of now the output is:
*Array before updating : 
Apple -- 3
Tomato -- 4
Jam -- 1

Array after updating :
Apple -- 3
Tomato -- 4
Jam -- 1
Orange -- 3
Tomato -- 8
Grape -- 20*

But I want output as:
*Array before updating : 
Apple -- 3
Tomato -- 4
Jam -- 1

Array after updating :
Apple -- 3
Tomato -- 12
Jam -- 1
Orange -- 3
Grape -- 20*

How do I change the code as to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes in the code and i am getting the required answer but not sure if its the best solution. If anyone has better solution please do post your answer.

---

```
class itemList{
    constructor(public name: string, public amount: number){}
}

function DisArr(Ar1: itemList[]){
    for(let item of Ar1){
        console.log(item.name + " -- " + item.amount);
    }
}

var Ar1 = [new itemList('Apple',3),
new itemList('Tomato',4),
new itemList('Jam',1)];

var Ar2 = [new itemList('Orange',3),
new itemList('Tomato',8),
new itemList('Grape',20)];

console.log("Array before updating : ");
DisArr(Ar1);

var delAr = [];
for(let i=0; i<Ar2.length; i++){
    for(let obj of Ar1){
        if(obj.name === Ar2[i].name){
            obj.amount += Ar2[i].amount;
            delAr.push(i);
        }
    }
}
for(let no of delAr){
    Ar2.splice(no,1);
}
Ar1.push(...Ar2);


console.log("Array before updating : ");
DisArr(Ar1);
---
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to create a new function `addToArrayOrIncrementAmount` which accepts an array to modify (`contextArray`) and an array of new values to add (`newArray`).

For each item in `newArray` check if that item exists in `contextArray`, using the `.name` property as an identifier (should be a unique id). If that identifier does not exist than push a new item, otherwise modify/increment the `amount` value with `+=`. Call this new function like `addToArrayOrIncrementAmount(Ar1, Ar2)`.

```js
class itemList {
  constructor(public name: string, public amount: number) { }
}

function DisArr(Ar1: itemList[]) {
  for (let item of Ar1) {
    console.log(item.name + " -- " + item.amount);
  }
}

function addToArrayOrIncrementAmount(contextArray: itemList[], newArray: itemList[]) {
  newArray.forEach(product => {
    const index = contextArray.findIndex((e) => e.name === product.name);

    if (index === -1) {
      contextArray.push(product);
    } else {
      contextArray[index].amount += product.amount;
    }
  });
}

var Ar1 = [new itemList('Apple', 3),
  new itemList('Tomato', 4),
  new itemList('Jam', 1)
];

var Ar2 = [new itemList('Orange', 3),
  new itemList('Tomato', 8),
  new itemList('Grape', 20)
];

console.log("Array before updating : ");
DisArr(Ar1);
addToArrayOrIncrementAmount(Ar1, Ar2);
console.log("Array before updating : ");
DisArr(Ar1);
```

Here it is as a JavaScript version just so I could insert into the answer and be able to demonstrate it works by clicking "Run code snippet".

```js
class itemList {
  constructor(name, amount) {
    this.name = name;
    this.amount = amount;
  }
}

function DisArr(Ar1) {
  for (let item of Ar1) {
    console.log(item.name + " -- " + item.amount);
  }
}

function addToArrayOrIncrementAmount(contextArray, newArray) {
  newArray.forEach(product => {
    const index = contextArray.findIndex((e) => e.name === product.name);

    if (index === -1) {
      contextArray.push(product);
    } else {
      contextArray[index].amount += product.amount;
    }
  });
}

var Ar1 = [new itemList('Apple', 3),
  new itemList('Tomato', 4),
  new itemList('Jam', 1)
];

var Ar2 = [new itemList('Orange', 3),
  new itemList('Tomato', 8),
  new itemList('Grape', 20)
];

console.log("Array before updating : ");
DisArr(Ar1);
addToArrayOrIncrementAmount(Ar1, Ar2);
console.log("Array before updating : ");
DisArr(Ar1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution use `reduce` method and remove duplicate in Ar2 and `concat` them as below

```
let result = Ar1.reduce((acc, item) => {
      let found = Ar2.find(c => c.name == item.name);
      if (found != undefined) {
        item.amount += found.amount;
        const index = Ar2.indexOf(found);
        if (index > -1) {
          Ar2.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
      acc.push(item);
      return acc;
    }, []);

    result = result.concat(Ar2);
```

Demo at stackbliz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-merge-array-reduce